# MySql : Get two random rows with different value

Tags: php, mysql, random, phpmyadmin

I have this table :

[image]

I want to get 2 random rows on condition be published and have different location values ( exemple : if the first row is vertical , the second must be horizontal).

I tried this

```
  SELECT * FROM publicity where published = 1 and location = 'vertical' 
   UNION 
  SELECT * FROM publicity where published = 1 and location = 'horizontal'
   ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2
```

It sometimes gives me 2 rows with the same location value.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Combine two queries that randomly select one for each location with UNION …

Comment: "Combine two queries that randomly select one for each location with UNION " @misorude You could that with union and a where filter indeed.

Comment: i put this : SELECT * FROM publicity where published = 1 and location = 'vertical'  
UNION
SELECT * FROM publicity where published = 1 and location = 'horizontal' 
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 2
and sometimes gives me 2 rows with the same location value

Comment: You need to apply the limit to the individual queries (and the order as well). Right now, you are reading _all_ records, order them randomly, and then limit the result to two.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference, please avoid using images for your tables. If you give the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE whatever` you will get the text of the table definition, and you can put that in your question. Also, please put the code you tried into your question, not a comment. You can always [edit] your question to give more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @misorude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement calls for random items from two different sets of items. One you've called `horizontal` and the other `vertical`. So, you must get those two random items, then take their union.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE location='horiz' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) h
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE location='vert' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) v
```

If you apply the `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` operation to the whole result set you might get both items from one location.

The two queries are wrapped in `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... ) a` because MySQL wants to apply `ORDER` and `LIMIT` clauses after it's taken the union..

Why `UNION ALL`? Because `UNION` deduplicates its result set, and you don't need to do that.

**Pro tip**: `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` works correctly, but it is notoriously slow, especially on large tables.